# Using codeigniter Models in another non-codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter, database-abstraction

I have 2 projects accessing the same DB. One is with CodeIgniter, the other is a home made mvc framework. I'd like to use the same Model layer.

Is it possible to access Codeigniter Models from another project?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why you would want to be accessing the same DB from two different frameworks at the same time (sounds like a recipe for disaster), but in general, I would say, "no."

Comment: could be a common db used for different purpose and it was dev by two team..ie: one front end for user and one admin project..they will both need to use user db or product db and both team are split at what works best. I do agree with you that if you are not using the same framework it might smell disaster but its not - not possible. Now the question is..can you extract CI's component that is this topic.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is not the `model` itself, You actually want the active records class located in /system/database/DB_active_rec, as that's the most common usage.

That class extends `CI_DB_driver`

This class accepts the config parameter for the DB(connection information).

You then want to extract the drivers themselves being used for the specific database you're working, the drivers can found at /system/database/drivers.

`CI->model` simply loads the `DB_active_rec`, that's why you need to do `$this->db->insert()`

I've never did so myself, But I don't see any major dependencies in the files themselves. I might have missed something though